# What is difference between "don't remember" and "not that remember"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Recently, I came across this use of the phrase: `not that I remember`. I have not encountered such use before. I have always come across the classic use of the phrase: `I don't remember`. Is there any difference between the classic phrase `I don't remember` and the recently met `not that I remember`?

Comment: Colloquially, they're equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not that I remember" is always used as a standalone response to something said before, and is more emphatic than "I don't remember," meaning something like "at least I don't remember":

A. Have you ever seen this man?

B. Not that I remember. (Perhaps I saw him, but now I don't remember.)

"I don't remember" does not carry that "at least" connotation, and can be followed by an object.

A. Have you ever seen this man?

B. I don't remember seeing him before.

Comment: That is, the phrase: "I don't remember" - has a confident character of statement. On the contrary, the phrase: "not that I remember" - has an uncertain character (maybe yes or maybe not). Right?

Comment: @MaximPro Exactly. "Not that I remember" would be equivalent to "No, as far as I rembember". It leaves room for the person not remembering correctly and therefore for the answer being wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by that:"...and therefore for the answer being wrong"?

Comment: @MaximPro I mean that, by saying "Not that I remember", the person is kind of excusing themselves from perhaps not giving an accurate answer.

Comment: Ahh, ok. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone "I don't remember" in response to a question means you don't know the answer. Conversely, "not that I remember" means something is false as far as you know, but could still be true unbeknownst to you. Its affirmative counterpart would be "as far as I remember."

Some related phrases mirror this distinction:

> *I don't know if he was at the party.* (I claim no knowledgeability on this subject.)
>
> *I don't know that he was at the party.* (It's possible that he was at the party, but I haven't seen or heard anything to indicate that he was, so I lean toward the assumption that he wasn't.)